YoloV8 model doesn't detect old dataset after retraining with new dataset
I'm trying to re-train a model which has been created with a sequence of a film.
After that, I want to re-train it with another sequence with the same labels, to see if it detects both sequences. But it does not do the right thing with the first one. If I re-train it with the first one once again, it doesn't detect the second sequence.
I've tried to re-train everything and nothing worked. Firstly, to create the model I did this.
yolo task=detect mode=test model=yolov8s.pt data=data.yaml epochs=100 imgsz=640

With the result, I select best.pt. After that, to re-train, I did this.
yolo task=detect mode=trait model=best.pt data=data.yaml epochs=10 imgsz=640


This is called “catastrophic forgetting”. You need to train on both datasets together. You can merge them in Roboflow.

Hi there ! Thank you so much for your answer ! Thinking of it, I have both datasets in different projects, is it possible anyway?

You need to merge the two datasets together, here is a nice docs linked by Brad
